# ngrams not in correct order

Tags: r, string, n-gram

I am interested to find the `ngrams` of a string `x= "A T G C C G C G T"` . I use the `ngram` `R` package to get the `ngrams`. I use following lines to get my job done.

```
library(ngram)    
ng <- ngram(x,n=2)
ngrams_out = get.ngrams(ng)
ngrams_final <-  gsub(" ", "",ngrams_out , fixed = TRUE)
# "CG" "TG" "AT" "GC" "CC" "GT" ## ngrams
```

It gives all the `ngrams` of the said string without repetition, but i am surprised that `ngrams` are not in correct order. The order is very important to trace the position of an `ngram`. The correct order of the `ngrams` is `"AT","TG","GC","CC","CG","GC","CG","GT"` with repetition, from where i can clearly make out the position of a particular `ngram` in the given string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about `ngram` but you should produce the output like this,

```
x= "A T G C C G C G T"
strsplit(gsub("(\\S)(?=\\s(\\S))|\\s+\\S$", "\\1\\2", x, perl=T), " ")[[1]]
# [1] "AT" "TG" "GC" "CC" "CG" "GC" "CG" "GT"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rQ7pL9/1)

Comment: What about `x= "ATGCCGCGT"`

Comment: What if I want to have combination of three or 4 or more at a time like `ATG,TGC,GCC,CCG,CGC,GCG,CGT` or `ATGC, TGCC,GCCG,CCGC,CGCG,GCGT`

Answer (score 3):

We can `scan` the string 'x' to get the individual characters, and then `paste` the adjacent elements together.

```
 v1 <- scan(text=x, what='')
 paste0(v1[-length(v1)], v1[-1])
 #[1] "AT" "TG" "GC" "CC" "CG" "GC" "CG" "GT"
```

For the updated question,

```
 x1 <- gsub('\\s+', '', x)
 n <- 3
 pat <- paste0('.{', n,'}')
 library(stringi)
 v1 <- c(stri_list2matrix(lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) 
    stri_extract_all_regex(substring(x1,i), pat)[[1]]),byrow=TRUE))
 v1[!is.na(v1)]
 #[1] "ATG" "TGC" "GCC" "CCG" "CGC" "GCG" "CGT"
```

Changing to

```
 n <- 4
 v1[!is.na(v1)]
 #[1] "ATGC" "TGCC" "GCCG" "CCGC" "CGCG" "GCGT"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yours answer works also for a string like `x = "ATGCCGCGT"`

Comment: @AaghazHussain  You can use `v1 <- strsplit(x,'')[[1]]` and then use the code.

Comment: Is there any side effect if i don't use this line.

Comment: @AaghazHussain  The idea is to split up the string into individual characters.  In the first case, there was already a delimiter i.e space.  Here, the characters are all concatenated together.  Suppose, you have `x <- 'A,T,G,C,C'`.  Use `sep=','` in `scan`

Comment: What if I want to have combination of three or 4 or more at a time like `ATG,TGC,GCC,CCG,CGC,GCG,CGT` or `ATGC, TGCC,GCCG,CCGC,CGCG,GCGT`

Answer (score 1):

The text analysis package **quanteda** has a great ngram generator:

```
require(quanteda)
unlist(tokenize("A T G C C G C G T", ngrams = 2, concatenator = ""))
## [1] "AT" "TG" "GC" "CC" "CG" "GC" "CG" "GT"
```

Here I have converted the tokenizedText class object (a type of list) returned from `tokenize()` into the simple vector you want.